# Finding the Optimum Point on a Curve

Tags: derivatives, optimization, curves

I am trying to find the optimum point on a curve. More specifically the function of the curve I am looking at is:

> $f(x)=e^{0.3*ln(x+1)}$

and the curve looks like this:

[image]

As I read in an old stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve)
the way would be create a straight line connecting the first and last points of the curve and pick the point of the curve that is furthest away from the straight line.

Is the way described above a valid one for this case?

If yes what is the mathematical explanation behind it and more importantly why should it be that specific point (what does the fact that it is the furthest point away from the straight line imply?).

If not what would be the way to go?

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by the "optimum point". This is not a commonly used term. The post that you link to seems not to be relevant here, because it deals with isolated data points, not a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, indeed I am not being clear. By optimum point (or points), I mean the point on the curve in which the increase of the value in X axis by 1 point, does not yield neither a very high nor a very low increase  in the value of Y (e.g. from x=1 to x=2, y increases in much higher rate than increasing from x=64 t ox=65). To sum it up, I am looking for a "balance" point on the curve in terms of how quickly Y changes by a consecutive X increase. That is why I thought the "elbow" rule seems applicable.

Comment: Your function is $f(x):=(x+1)^{0.3}$, but the picture shows something else.

Comment: I'm afraid you are still not being clear. You have to tell us what you want if you want us to help!

Comment: @TonyK Well I am also afraid that I don't know exactly what I am looking for! My main goal is to find a point on the curve above, that is preferable from any other point for this range of X values (x=1 until X=66). To be explicitly honest I would like to find a way to explain why any point between x=5 to x=12 is preferable in any way, as long as there is a solid argumentation about it (if any).

Comment: Preferable _by what criterion_? We can't read your mind!

Comment: I don't know! What criterions are there? Say you had the graph and function above, and you had to present it to a client and tell him that "ok look you should have x=9-x=12" and be able to give a proper argumentation about it.